# starting symfony: logging out

Tags: security, symfony

I am working through some very basic symfony examples and having a problem logging out. Please note: this is not related to cookies and basic auth. I have tried to set up an /admin firewall to require basic auth and then logout. this works ok with the "pattern: /admin commented out but fails if I uncomment it - with the message "Unable to find the controller for path "/logout". The route is wrongly configured". Why is the pattern entry breaking the logout?

file contents below:

**routing.yml**

```
logout:
    path: /logout
```

**security.yml**

```
security:
    admin:
       pattern: /admin
       anonymous: ~
       http_basic: ~
       logout:
          path:   /logout
          target: /

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncomment pattern: `/admin` and modify `logout` as follows

```
logout:
  path: /admin/logout
```

So, basically you will have

```
security:
    admin:
       pattern: /admin
       anonymous: ~
       http_basic: ~
       logout:
          path:   /admin/logout
          target: /

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

#### Explaination

This because Symfony expects you to have logout action "under" same "pattern" of your firewall.

#### Why?

That's because you're not defining any controller (and of course you don't have to) and the framework expects a url that match at least to one firewall (you don't need to logout if you have any firewall against you need an authentication, right?).
This is due to security listeners that are only attached when the request matches the pattern of the firewall.

Comment: ok that worked. thank you. how do i modify my configuration for multiple secured areas? the routing.yml file logout: path: config would need multiple entries for multiple firewalls?

Comment: @LaurenceFass: you need to define another firewall (like you've done with admin but changing names)

Comment: Don I have defined another firewall but Im not clear on the routing.yml config to allow for two logout paths.

Comment: @LaurenceFass: create another question (as it's not related strictly to this one)

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to add this to your routing.yml file:

```
_logout:
    path: /logout
```

And then in security.yml:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            logout: ~
```

Basically Symfony expects a named route _logout unless some other pattern is defined. The easiest way in my opinion is to just create the route and give it a path. There is no need to give the route a default controller as Symfony will pick up the route and know what to do with it. Hope that helps.